# Why does IE implement console.log() differently from Safari, Chrome, and Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console

If you use console.log() with out checking for its existence it breaks the code in IE.  Once you go into debug it using the debugger....it begins to work masking the actual issue.

Because of this Catch-22 you never get to see the actual fail.

This is not a problem in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Where can I file this as a bug ( a very ambiguous one ) and why does IE do this?

Comment: If we started asking why IE did every thing it did wrong wrong...

Comment: A Bug in a Microsoft Product? Never! heh.

Comment: `<rant>`This is because IE is a terrible product, and their team forgot that people actually need to develop for it. Their dev tools were first created in IE6, and haven't been updated at all since.  I know in old versions of IE, the `console` only existed with the dev tools opened, no one knows why.  I think the IE team is just trying to make people's lives miserable.`</rant>`.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist This is fixed in IE10, I've just tested it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this happened in old Firefox too (v. 3.6?)

Comment: @duri: I though it was fixed in IE9.

Comment: I just verified in IE8 and IE9...I'm not lying or making this up.

Comment: @Xeon06...asking why is a way to keep Microsoft Dumb from getting on you...don't accept it...fight the dumb.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: We know this is a real issue, and no, you cannot file a bug report for it.  Like M$ would care anyway.  The solution is to make sure you have the dev tools open *before* loading your site.

Comment: Well...I know that I have about 10 more issues like this to go through before I get IE up an running.  I need a productive place to rant...like a Microsoft Bug Reporter...I don't expect change...just a place to rant on Microsoft...maybe make copies and drop leaflets...on Microsoft Campus or something...just kidding.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/ is a place where to open IE bug reports but this issue is already fixed.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: I feel your pain, we all do.  IE is a horrible development platform.  We've all had to deal with it.  Get a glass of water and calm down.  Go for a walk. When you come back, install [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html).  :-)

Comment: @duri: That seems to be for IE10 only?

Comment: @Rocket Yes because IE10 **is** an update for older IE versions. You would never fill a report with a bug that happens in Firefox 3.5, it doesn't make sense. It's the same with IE8.

Comment: @duri: Thing is, people *actually* update Firefox.  I have a problem with those people who are still using IE7, and have *never* updated!

Comment: You can file the bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/ie, but I know for a fact it's already been filed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't experience this problem. `console.log` works just fine even when the console has never been opened.

However, in older versions of browsers, without a console, you can always shim it:

```
console = console || {log:function() {
    var l = arguments.length, i, arr = [];
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) arr[i] = arguments[i];
    alert(arr.join("\n"));
}};
```

Comment: I just tested it on IE8 and IE9....I tested it w/ and w/ out to verify the error....

Comment: I know in IE8, if you don't have the dev tools opened, `console` is `undefined` so, `console.log` will throw an error and stop the JavaScript from executing.

Comment: Well, whether I am right or wrong, the shim can still be used just fine as a console substitute. But to be honest you should have the console open if you are attempting to debug using `console.log` anyway, and you should never leave any `console.log` calls in production.

Comment: +1 for pasting code that works and not presenting any opinions or starting argument. But please rather use `window.console = window.console || { log: ...` because it relies on undeclared assignment, see http://perfectionkills.com/onloadfunction-considered-harmful/